# XSLT - identify node followed by another node

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a xml like this,

```
<doc>
    <p>para<x>para</x>para<x>para</x>para</p>
    <p>para<x>para</x><x>para</x>para</p>
</doc>
```

I need to add a ',' between `<x>` nodes if couple of `<x>` placed successively (`<x>` followed by another `<x>`node).

so, for above example xml, output should be,

```
<doc>
    <p>para<x>para</x>para<x>para</x>para</p>
    <p>para<x>para</x>,<x>para</x>para</p>
</doc>
```

I tried to write a xsl template fo identify successive `<x>` noted and added the ',' as follows,

```
 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="x[following-sibling::*[1][self::x]]">
        <x>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </x>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
```

but it adds the ',' to the above both scenarios. (`<x>` followed by another `<x>`node and `<x>` followed by text)

Any idea to correct this xpath?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `following-sibling::*[1]` the XPath only check for the nearest following sibling *element*, not considering *text nodes*. Try using `following-sibling::node()[1]` instead :

```
<xsl:template match="x[following-sibling::node()[1][self::x]]">
    <x>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </x>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```